Generate UTF-8 MD5 hash for Chinese in SQL Server
SELECT LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'a'), 2));

Result : 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
This is OK.
SELECT LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', '啊'), 2));

Result : 795d6a1c51f0ac4b0856f5cac1846f3f
The correct result is 04c16ff7b157d4b4702bb24aa62651a5
Why do I get a wrong result?
Please solve my question, thanks!

What does HASHBYTES('MD5', N'啊') give you?

To get your desired result, you need to take the MD5 hash of the UTF8 encoding of your string. This can be done by applying a UTF8 collation to your string and converting to VARCHAR. Adding an N prefix to your string literal is also required.
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'啊' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8)
    );

Or (with your preferred formatting):
SELECT LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),
    HASHBYTES('MD5',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'啊' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8)
    ),
    2));

Result: 04c16ff7b157d4b4702bb24aa62651a5
Compare with this MD5 online encoding site
Site note: T-SQL declared @variables cannot generally be used to store UTF-8 encoded text, because variables will always use the default database collation regardless of and COLLATE specification used in the assigned expression. The exception is when the default database collation is actually set to a UTF-8 collation. Thus, the following may not work:
DECLARE @Utf8String VARCHAR(MAX) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), N'啊' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8)
SELECT @Utf8String, HASHBYTES('MD5', @Utf8String);

See this db<>fiddle for a demo that includes a few more sample strings and a comparison between UTF-16 encoding and UTF-8 encoding.
